# How to activate FULL $var completion

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu, debian, bash-completion

under Debians BASH I can do the following:

```
foo=/path/to/some/file

cat $f[TAB]
```

As you can see, I can autocomplete the variable $foo by pressing TAB.

Under Ubuntu (11) the behaviour is not the same (I've activated '/etc/bash_completion' in my bashrc).

This is working:

```
echo $f[TAB]
```

This one is not working:

```
cat $f[TAB]
```

Can anyone give me a hint, how to get the last one working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the completion specification provided for `cat` by `/etc/bash_completion` by doing:

```
complete -r cat
```

or you can see if modifying the completion options provided in `/etc/bash_completion` work in the version of Bash you're using:

```
complete -F _longopt -o filenames -o bashdefault cat
```

If you're using the latest patched version of Bash 4.2, there is an option that may help (I haven't tried it):

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

Comment: Okay.. that fixed my problem for "cat".. but using "grep" etc issues the same problem. Do I have to do this on every program I use or is there a global way?

Comment: @casper: You can try replacing `_longopt()` with a no-op: `_longopt() { :; }` but that's likely to break other things. You could run a loop: `for p in cat grep; do complete -r "$p"; done`. You can modify `_longopt()` so that when `$cur` starts with a "$" it sets `COMPREPLY` to a `compgen` consisting of variable names. There might be other ways. Does my second suggestion in my answer work for you?

Comment: I disabled the line `. /etc/bash_completion`. in `~/.bashrc`. Now its working. I think this is the most elegant way not bricking other stuff. The fact that I have to disable completion to get completion is a bit wired in my oppinion ;-)

Comment: @casper: You've disabled some *programmed* completion to get *default* completion. Note (for completeness) that you have not disabled *programmable* completion - `shopt -u progcomp` does that - though I don't know why anyone would want to.